# Reset Filter on xceed datagrid using a button

Tags: wpf, xceed-datagrid

I have a filtering row in my xceed datagrid. There are around 8 columns. The user can enter the filter criteria for each column.

Now what I want to do is reset the whole filter using a single button.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. I simply created a command `ClearFilterCommand` in my ViewModel whose execute method is `ClearFilter`

```
private void ClearFilter (object obj)
{
  if (obj != null && obj is DataGridControl)
    DataGridCommands.ClearFilter.Execute (null, obj as DataGridControl);
}

<Button Content="Clear Grid Filter" Command="{Binding ClearFilterCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=xceedgrid}"/>
```

`xceedgrid` is the name of my xceed `DataGrid` in the xaml.